# Django admin view_on_site redirect gives me extra https:// on production

Tags: python, django, django-admin

view_on_site works perfect on localhost, but when I tried in production return this:
https://https//expample.com//accounts/details/9/
What can i do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but when I detele view_on_site = True and override view_on_site method to this:

```
def view_on_site(self, obj):
    return obj.get_absolute_url()
```

It fixed.